# I can't figure how to install postgresql10.7 in ruby on rails on windows8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

While going through Michael Hartl's book on RubyonRails, I decided to go with postgresql instead of the sqlite3 version used in the book(Although, I can't get the sqlite3 gem install in RubyonRails but am less concern since my focus is on using pg) and this are the steps I have taken so far

Step1: I downloaded the postgreSQL version 10.7 and installed it
Step2: Add The path to the path environment
Step3: I added it to the

> > Gemfile
> >     like this 
> >     'pg', '~>10.7'

Step4: Run

> > Rails bundle

WHAT I GOT FROM THE CONSOLE

> > Could not find gem 'pg (= 10.7) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in
> >     your Gemfile.

My question is how can I install the version or any other version of pg on Ruby on Rails in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, have been able to figure it out myself and these are what I do
I comment out the sqlite3 like this

> > gem install 'sqlite3'

replace it with

> > gem install 'pg'

after that, I go to

> > config folder

and select the

> > database.yml

and change the settings to these

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  username: postgresql
  password: your password
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_dating

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_dating_test
```

The name of the database I created is called

> > db_dating

so remember to change yours to your db name